# Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures

Tags: align, amsmath, pandoc

When I run `pandoc periodic.md -o example.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex --template eisvogel --listings -VCJKmainfont="Microsoft YaHei"`, pandoc reported an error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.430 \end{align}
```

BTW, I use [pandoc-latex-template](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) so there is `--template eisvogel` in the command.

Here's my markdown source file.
Actually, this document is written in another language and this is the reason why there is `-VCJKmainfont="Microsoft YaHei"` in the command I executed. For easy understanding, I translate it into English.

```
---
title: "Cyclical phenomena in life"
author: [andylizf]
date: "2019.3.23"
keywords: [Markdown]
---


## Definition of periodicity

In general, for the function $f(x)$, if there is a non-zero constant $T$, such that for every $x$ in the domain,
$$
f(x + T) = f(x)
$$
For a periodic function $f(x)$, if there is a smallest positive number in all its cycles, then this smallest positive number is called the smallest positive period of $f(x)$.

## Periodic phenomena in mathematics

### Trigonometric function

According to the induction formula,
$$
\begin{align}
    \sin x&= \sin(x + 2\pi) \label{eq1}\\
    \cos x&= \cos(x + 2\pi) \label{eq2}\\
    \tan x&= \tan(x + \pi) \label{eq3}\\
\end{align}
$$
```

Comment: Provide a full example.

Comment: Welcome! I think that `Something irrelevant...` has something very relevant in. Perhaps an unmatched `$`.

Comment: And please provide the generated LaTeX file, as most of us do not work in markdown

Comment: I'm using pandoc to convert markdown to pdf, so there may not be a LaTex file.

Comment: Change `align` to `aligned` as instructed by the error message.

Comment: But I want to number each equation so I use `align` instead of `aligned`.

Comment: First of lever use `$$...$$` with latex, secondly `align` is an outer display math construction, so is `$$...$$`. WIth very few exceptions outer math constructions cannot be nested inside each other. So if you want equation numbers just remove the `$$...$$` and `align` will give them too you.

Comment: @daleif - Just a remark:  `$...$` and `$$...$$` are correct in pandoc's markdown and will result in `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` when the output format is LaTeX.

Comment: After I remove `$$..$$ ` that nested it, it works. Thank you for helping me, but can you explain one more time? (sorry for my poor English @DG'

Comment: @DG' that is on the pandoc people. Users should not be using `$$...$$`. I don't understand why they support it in the first place as `\[...\]` is much easier to parse. You see the `$$...$$` syntax promoted in other non LaTeX apps, where again `\[...\]` would be so much easier for them to parse.

Comment: @daleif - I know. You can force the correct behaviour with the following option: `--from markdown-tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash`

Comment: @DG' can you tell me where I'd place this command?  It this something I enter into R Studio in my YAML header or does this need to go someplace else on the pandoc side?

Comment: When you call pandoc on the command line, just add the options: `$ pandoc --from markdown-tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash in.md -o out.pdf`

Comment: Related question with different solution [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049762/erroneous-nesting-of-equation-structures-in-using-beginalign-in-a-multi-l).

Answer (score 8):

The `{align}` or `{align*}` environment is like the `{equation}` or `{equation*}` environments and are used for arranging equations of multiple lines. (Use the asterisk to avoid automatic numbering of equations.)  When you place an `{align}` environment inside `$$`, it is equivalent to nesting an equation environment inside another equation environment, hence the error message "Erroneous nesting of equation structures."

As you appear to have already discovered, simply remove the `$$` surrounding the `\begin{align}...\end{align}`, and your markdown will set properly.

Other environments you may wish to explore are `{multline}` or `{multline*}` to left-align the first equation, and right-align the last equation, `{gather}` or `{gather*}` to write consecutive equations without alignment, `{flalign}` or `{flalign*}` that works like `{align}` but right-aligns what occurs after the ampersand, and `{alignat}` or `{alignat*}` that allows for several columns of equation to be aligned rather than just 2.